# What does while(!a) mean when a is a number?

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

Trying to decipher this bit of C code:

```
int WaitForPacket(uint16 milliseconds, Dexcom_packet* pkt, uint8 channel) {
uint32 start = getMs();
uint8 * packet = 0;
uint32 i = 0;
uint32 seven_minutes = 420000;
int nRet = 0;
swap_channel(nChannels[channel], fOffset[channel]);

while (!milliseconds || (getMs() - start) < milliseconds) {
    i++;
    if(!(i % 60000)) {
        strobe_radio(channel);
    }
    doServices();
    if((getMs() - start) > seven_minutes) {
        killWithWatchdog();
        delayMs(2000);
    }
    blink_yellow_led();
    if (packet = radioQueueRxCurrentPacket()) {
        uint8 len = packet[0];
        fOffset[channel] += FREQEST;
        memcpy(pkt, packet, min8(len+2, sizeof(Dexcom_packet)));
        if(radioCrcPassed()) {
            if(pkt->src_addr == dex_tx_id || dex_tx_id == 0 || only_listen_for_my_transmitter == 0) {
                pkt->txId -= channel;
                radioQueueRxDoneWithPacket();
                LED_YELLOW(0);
                return 1;
            } else {
                radioQueueRxDoneWithPacket();
            }
        } else {
            radioQueueRxDoneWithPacket();
            LED_YELLOW(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
LED_YELLOW(0);
return nRet;
}
```

The code is pretty readable, and I get what's going on for the most part (except that `uint8 * packet = 0`, isn't that a null pointer?), but I'm not sure what's going on with the `!milliseconds` in the condition for the while loop. Is it just a bitwise NOT? What does that mean? When is a bitwise NOT true and when is it false, if there's more than one bit?

Comment: Regarding `uint8_t * packet = 0`, yes it's a null pointer.

Comment: Isn't that a problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure, aren't null pointers bad things? Or is it just a pointer to the very first location in memory?

Comment: Null pointers are not a bad thing, it's dereferencing a null pointer that is a bad thing. Here the `packet` pointer is initialized to `0` only to give it a known initial value, you can see from the program that it is later assigned to the value returned by the `radioQueueRxCurrentPacket` function.

Comment: Aha, it's an =, not an ==. `=` is a function that returns true/1 when the assignment is successful, right?

Comment: These answers(including the accepted one) do not explain what `!` does and what `WHILE` does, and that `=` is part of intialization in a definition. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 !milliseconds
```

is equivalent to:

```
  (milliseconds == 0)
```

by definition of the `!` operator:

> (C11, 6.5.3.3p5) "[...] The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E)."

Comment: But the `==` expression returns 0 or 1 and the WHILE uses *that*.

Answer (score 1):

In C, 0 is false. While any other number is evaluated as true.

So, `while(!a)` is the same as `while( a == 0 )`

Logic:

`(!a)` will only yield true when `a == 0`

`(a == 0)` will only yield true when `a == 0` :)

Comment: By your definition `while(!a)` is the same as `while( !(a != 0) )`, that is equivalent with `while( a == 0 )`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski you are right, fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!a)
```

the part in brackets is, of course, a logical statement - normally something like

```
(a==0)
```

The way the code works is that if the logic is true it is assigned value of 1 (or at least not zero) and if it is false then it is assigned 0.

so

```
(1)
```

means true and

```
(0)
```

means false

Now the ! reverses true and false - it is a 'not' command

so

```
(!1)
```

is false and

```
(!0)
```

is true and....

```
(!a)
```

means true if a==0 and false if a<>0

Answer (score 0):

the sign "!" means "not" as you probably slready know,
whe you have an expression, if it has a positive value it will be translate to boolean "true" 
else(negative or 0), it eil be translated to boolean "false"
now add the "not" sign and for each you eill get the opposite,
e.g
a>0 :
!a will be false

a<0 or a=0:
!a will be true

Answer (score 0):

In initialization, assignment or comparison to a pointer, literal `0` is taken as the null pointer value. The null pointer value compares equal only to itself and literal `0`. It does not point to anything and cannot be dereferenced.

Pointers can be compared for equality to pointers and literal `0` and pointers into the same array can be compared with inequalities.

In an `IF` or a `WHILE`, if the expression between `(` & `)` is `== 0` (arithmetic or the null pointer value) then the condition is taken to be false, otherwise true.

Operator `!` returns one when its argument is `== 0` (arithmetic or the null pointer value) and otherwise returns zero. Similarly the relational operators `==`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` return one when the condition is true and zero when the condition is false.

So for `IF (!a)` and `WHILE (!a)` the `!a` will equal one or zero; if `a` equals zero then `WHILE(!a)` is `WHILE(1)`, otherwise it is `WHILE(0)`. `WHILE` takes non-zero as condition true and zero as condition false.

Note how all the other answers do not make clear the difference between the value of an expression and what `IF` and `WHILE` do with a zero vs other values, ie how it interprets them as conditions.

This has nothing to do with bits. Numbers are compared as numbers and pointers are compared as pointers.

PS: `uint8_t * packet = 0` is a definition of variable `packet` of type `uint8_t *` ie "pointer to uint8_t" intitialized per the `=` (suggesting assignment) to `0`.

PPS: `while (!milliseconds || (getMs() - start) < milliseconds)` says, loop if milliseconds is 0, otherwise loop if time < milliseconds. So passing 0 for milliseconds means always loop, without testing for time < milliseconds; and passing non-zero for milliseconds means loop while time < milliseconds. (Either way `killWithWatchdog()` is called when time >= seven_minutes.)